# Syntax : 'x' is a 'variable' but is used as a 'method'

Tags: c#, variables, methods, unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject explosionPrefab;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision otherObj) {
    GameObject explosionObject = Instantiate(explosionPrefab, otherObj.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    explosionObject(explosionObject, 5f); <-- THE LINE GIVING ERROR
    Destroy(otherObj.gameObject);
    }
}
```

I am in confusion because I haven't been doing scripting for that long and was wondering if anyone could show me the right way to do this, it is for a small test game on unity. Just wondering how this is fixed and so that I don't make this mistake in the future.

Comment: Well what do you expect `explosionObject(...)` to do? That looks like a method call - what are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to call a method? Do something else?

Comment: The error is clear enough. To correct the code will require knowledge of what you are hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

**In General**

A method declaration:

```
void x() {
    // do something
}
```

A call to that method:

```
x();
```

A declaration of a varialble:

```
int x = 0;
```

Use of the variable:

```
x = 7; //write
y = x; //read and assing to another variable
```

**Your code**

You declared a variable:

```
GameObject explosionObject = Instantiate(explosionPrefab, otherObj.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

But then you use it *like* a method:

```
 explosionObject(explosionObject, 5f); <-- THE LINE GIVING ERROR
```

You may missed the method name, in case that you want to call a method of the GameObject instance? For example:

```
 explosionObject.MyMethod(explosionObject, 5f);
```

Or you may used the same name for your instance and another method, then try to change the name of you instance of GameObject:

```
GameObject game = Instantiate(explosionPrefab, otherObj.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
explosionObject(game, 5f);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is very clear, lets have a look on your code below:

```
explosionObject(explosionObject, 5f);
```

Here you have declared `explosionObject` as a `GameObject` variable and and you are using the same name for your method that's why this issue is occurring. Either change the variable name or the function name and your issue get resolved.